# How can I remove one Brave browser where it is installed twice on my OS. How do i identify which to uninstall

Tags: delete, brave

I am running Ubuntu Budgie 22.04 and have Brave browser installed. Somehow I have Brave installed two times. I can identify on the programs menu which one I want to delete. How do I delete that specific one. Right clicking on the Brave Icon in the programs menu shows nothing. Can someone guide me with specific steps. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Brave browser was installed as a snap package. Uninstall the brave snap package (in order to remove the two Brave icons in the Dash programs menu) and reinstall it.  Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap remove brave
sudo snap install brave
```

If you still have a Brave browser apt package installed it should show up in Synaptic package manager's GUI, and you can also uninstall it from Synaptic. Run `sudo apt install synaptic` to install Synaptic.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to do it, is to find out the version you want removed (start the app and check settings or Help menu), then run `sudo apt-get list --installed brave-browser` in the terminal.

I don't know the particulars of brave browser, but I suspect you have 2 different versions installed.

Note the package name and remove it via `sudo apt-get remove <package name>`

Comment: Unfortunately I find that they are the same version. One was installed via SNAP and the other by Terminal. It seems that one did not overwrite the other. The Synaptic package manager shows that only one is installed ??? there are two links in the .bin folder